# Replace "dot" with "comma" using biber and verbose-trad1

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'd like to have a "comma" instead of a "dot" after the authors and before the title. In other words, replace the "dot" for a "comma" as the author-title separator...

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@Book{clone,
  author = {Maniatis, T. and Fritsch, E. F. and Sambrook, J.},
  title = {Molecular Cloning: A Laboratory Manual},
  year = {2001},
  publisher = {Cold Spring Harbor Laboratory},
  location = {New York},
  edition = {3}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is just a test\footcite{clone}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}{%
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{edition}%
}
{%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock
\printfield{edition}%
}{}{}

\renewcommand\labelnamepunct{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@Book{clone,
  author = {Maniatis, T. and Fritsch, E. F. and Sambrook, J.},
  title = {Molecular Cloning: A Laboratory Manual},
  year = {2001},
  publisher = {Cold Spring Harbor Laboratory},
  location = {New York},
  edition = {3}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is just a test\footcite{clone}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard. Just one more question: does this solution impacts other sections of a document or other parts of the bibliography?

Comment: I'm not too sure of what you refer to, and I don't well enough the internals of biblatex, but, as I understand it, it only changes the punctuation after (list of) author(s), editor(s) and the like

Comment: I was referring to the fact that the command `\labelnamepunct` could eventually change something else, but I've found that it doesn't. Now, I've read the bib latex manual in order to find the same thing to change the punctuation after the title: same thing,  I need rather a "comma" that a "dot". Do you know to do it, please? In your example, it would be a "comma" after _Manual_

Comment: See my updated code. We have to patch the bibliography driver for the ‘book’  entry type. The `xpatch` package is done for that.